# How can I modify this powershell code in Active Directory, to be able to change attributes when emply cells from csv file?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a csv file with datas:

```
SamAccountName;MobilePhone;surname
abc;2313;abc
bca;;bca
cba;3243>cba
```

How can I change this code to replace the cells where no data is available. For example I can't change the **bca** user attributes because no mobilephone available.

Here is the code:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Import-Csv "C:\jo.csv" -Delimiter ';' |
ForEach-Object{
Set-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Surname $_.surname -Givenname $_.givenname -Displayname $_.displayname -Title
$_.Title -Department $_.Department -Manager $_.Manager -OfficePhone $_.HomePhone -MobilePhone $_.MobilePhone
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something called [splatting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts/) in PowerShell, where you construct the parameters into an object and feed that object to the cmdlet instead of each individual parameter.

Something like this:

```
$params = @{Identity = $_.SamAccountName}
if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.surname)) {
    $params.Surname = $_.surname
}
if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.givenname)) {
    $params.Givenname = $_.givenname
}
#Do the same for all the other parameters

Set-ADUser @params
```

Comment: Can you insert the full code? How can I import the csv file?

Comment: You import the CSV exactly the same way you were in your original code. The code I gave you can go inside the `ForEach-Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the null values you can always use a replace command.
In your script:

```
$Temp = "C:\jo.csv" 
(Get-Content $Temp -Raw) -replace '""','"-"' | Set-Content $Temp
#Replace the "" with "-" because the set-aduser can not complete with null values
```

After that you can simply run the Set-ADUser command.